# Dozer deep mapping a polymorphic object

Tags: java, dozer

Classes:

```
public class X { A a;}
public abstract class A { String a; }
public class B extends A { D d;  }
public class C extends A { D d; }
public class D { String x; }

public class Y { String a; String x;}
```

Mapping:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>X</class-a>
    <class-b>Y</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>a.a</a>
        <b>a</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>a.d.x</a>
        <b>x</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Here for in `a.d.x` object `d` can either be of class `B` or `C`. How can I specify the type for object `d`.

Tried `<a-hint>B</a-hint>` which didn't work.